# Why Macros recorded with errors in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am recording a macro to automatically generate the lines of code. After I start the macro and stopped recording, I check the code. Immediately, I receive a "Syntax Error".

This was a recorded macro, why would it generate a wrong code?

The code below is exactly how it was recorded.

I have Excel 2016 in WindoWs 10.

Thank you

```
Sub FixFilter()
'
' FixFilter Macro
'

'
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet(, .(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveSheet(, .(xlDown)).Select
.
ActiveSheet.Enabled  := 10
.ActiveSheet("$A$1:$T$841"). Index := 20, BringToFront := "<>"
Range("R545").Select
End Sub
```

NEW RECORDED MACRO:

```
Sub TestFilter()
'
' TestFilter Macro
'

'
Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet(, .(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveSheet(, .(xlDown)).Select
.
ActiveSheet.Copy  := 1
.ActiveSheet("$A$1:$T$841"). Index := 20, BringToFront := "<>"
Range("W503").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: If it has a syntax error - at least try debugging it and seeing what the line is and adding that information to the question. I think the dot on a line all by itself is your issue though. Try deleting that whole line and saving and trying again. I daresay you inadvertently hit the dot in the macro and saved it when you saved your spreadsheet.

Comment: And the dot at the beginning of this line looks like a typo too: .ActiveSheet("$A...

Comment: I have recorded the same Macro and re-posted exactly as it is. It looks wrong. This never happened before, why would a macro generate a code with a syntax error?

Comment: Any thoughts please?